# Spring MVC - @PathVariable -Failed to find resource

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

In my Spring MVC demo project I am using path variable annotation.
Controller looks like below.

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/login"})
    public class HelloWorldController {

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String helloWorld(final Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World!");
            System.out.println("hello world");
            return "jsp/login.jsp";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String getLoginId(@PathVariable final int id, final Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World!");
            System.out.println("hello world 2" + id);
            return "jsp/login.jsp";
        }
    }
```

Now when I trying to access the below url
*http://localhost:9080/ExampleSpring/login* 
the controller is going to login.jsp page. This is an expected result.

but when the url is changed to 
*http://localhost:9080/ExampleSpring/login/9*
I am getting the below error and java.io.FileNotFoundException: JSPG0036E: **Failed to find resource /login/jsp/login.jsp**

Could anybody please tell me the reason behind this?

Comment: Are you sure your controllers are invoked? Are 'hello world' texts displayed in console and jsp?

Comment: not sure how is your setup, but view name is usually without ".jsp", ie. either "jsp/login" or more likely only "login"

Comment: @jgr Yes my controller is invkoed in both the cases. And Hello worid is printed in the console. in my project set up ihave created a folder 'jsp' inside web-inf and i am return the view name as jsp/login.jsp. In the later case the view is returning as '/login/jsp/login.jsp'.

Comment: @sodik I am not using view resolver, thats why i have given full view name IE. 'jsp/login.jsp'.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I guess this could a reason and solution .. I guess for the former case ie. *http://localhost:9080/ExampleSpring/login* case it tries to look for the resource after the context root that is inside WEB-INF. But in the later case as it is ecountered a second / after /login it tries to find the resource inside WEB-INF/login folder which actually does not exists, thus the error came.

Soulution could be , to use "../jsp/login.jsp" which will force to check the resource from the context root. What ever long request string u can pass this will ensure that the resources are searched from the context root. 
May be thats why to avoid this confusion spring has come up with View Resolver. 
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand you comments, you have no configured view resolver, so you simply forward to the view passed as view name.

As you have no initial `/` you fall in the hell of relative URLs. In that case, you should write :

```
        return "/jsp/login.jsp";
```

if the view is at `/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp`

BTW, the reason for `ViewResolvers` is (among others such as easy refactoring) to do that low level work of adding `/jsp/` as prefix and `.jsp` as suffix. So IMHO, you really should considere to add one to your config.

Comment: @Serger Thanks for ur answer.. now its working fine with /jsp/login.jsp and with ../jsp/login.jsp also. :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you should put :

`....@PathVariable("id") int id ....`